# Angular2 Production Mode link to vendor folder

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

I am making an Angular2 project with the angular-cli npm package. I want to upload the app to the server and I runned those commands: `ng build --prod` and `ng serve --prod`. When I uploaded the dist folder to the server and open it from the url it says that it can't load the resources from the vednor folder (es6-shim, reflected-metadata, systemjs and zone.js). Is it possible to run the app only from the `index.html` file or I need to run the `ng serve` command on the server. Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="./vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
    System.import('main');
  }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: where is your `<base href="/"> ` pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add `dist` folder in your server. `ng build` will build your `dist` folder. Then `ng serve` will run your application

Comment: Yes but the problem is that there isn't on the server npm and also it is a Java Spring project so for that reason I need only index.html.

Comment: but what if i have to add the external js file while `ng build`  ? apart from dist folder ?